# dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) called inside captureOutput(didOutputSampleBuffer:_) causes memory pressure

Tags: ios, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I am working on a video recording app using a pretty standard setup getting CMSampleBufferRef objects from `captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`.  We are converting the sample buffers into `UIImage` objects and setting the image on a `UIImageView`.  Setting the `.image` property on the `UIImageView` needs to be performed on the main thread of course so that operation is called in a`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` block.  Adding the call to the main thread causes memory pressure inside `didOutputSampleBuffer:` causes memory usage to grow at a rate of about 500kb/s.

Here is the code sample to replicate the memory pressure.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 

  }

}
```

[image]

I have tried using an optional for the `dispatch_block_t` block and setting it to nil after the operation has completed.  I have also tried using `NSOperationQueue` but the same problem occurs.

I am running Swift 2.3 on iOS 10.3.2

Comment: Video sample buffers are large, so you must minimize the amount of time you reference them, otherwise your memory footprint will grow very quickly (although 500kb/s is too low for you to be leaking video frames, maybe show some more code?)

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I've been able to conclude that referencing the sample buffers is not the cause of the issue.  The line `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }` causes the memory pressure.  Removing that line fixes the problem... as strange as it seems

Comment: So that empty dispatch block causes a leak?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman yes, according to the memory reporter in Xcode.  After lots of searching I've come to understand that Xcode's memory usage is not always accurate and I should be using allocations in Instruments instead to debug memory.  Unfortunately Instruments crashes each time I launch a program :)